# Question which is sort of puzzle from mathematics Exam

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, liars

I am self studying and trying questions of quantitative aptitude in my mathematics exam and I am unable to solve this problem.

[image: logic problem transcript below]

> Of three persons $A$, $B$ and $C$, one always lies while the others always speak the truth. $C$ asked $A$, "Do you always speak the truth, yes or no?" He said something that $C$ could not hear. So, $C$ asked $B$. "what did $A$ say?" $B$ replied, "$A$ said No".
>
> So, who is the liar?

The answer, supposedly, is

> $B$.

Unfortunately, I am completely clueless on how to approach this question. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: It would help if you gave the question to which “B” is the answer. I assume the question is “Who always lies?”

Comment: @Damila I am really sorry. I cropped by mistake the last line" So, who is the liar" ? Kindly accept apologies!!

Comment: It’s ok! If you don’t mind, I hid the answer in your question for future readers.

Comment: @Damila since I cannot see your edit suggestion, I added the spoiler tag myself. (at)user795826 can you please provide the source of this problem? The title of the book from which this puzzle came from should be enough

Comment: @melfnt its from previous year papers of an exam. Not from a book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the question posed is "Who always lies?" then the answer is indeed.

> $B$.

We can approach this problem by noticing that

> $A$ must have said "yes," yet $B$ claimed that $A$ said "no."

This can be deduced like this:

> $A$ is asked "Do you speak the truth?"
>
>   - If $A$ is truthful, they will truthfully say "yes."
>   - If $A$ always lies, they will lie and say "yes."
>
>  Therefore, $A$'s answer to the first question is always "yes." Hence, by claiming that $A$ said "no," $B$ is the liar.